# cx_freeze help AssertionError

Tags: python, pygame, cx-freeze

Hi I was using cx_freeze 2.7 for a tutorial I was following and every time I used the program it would come up with an AssertionError. Here is my setup.py file if anyone wants to see:

```
    import cx_Freeze 

    executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("Slither.py")]
    cx_Freeze.setup( 
         name = "Slither", 
         options = {"build_exe": {"packages":["pygame"],"include_files": ["apple.png","snakehead.png","funnydog.png"]}},
    executables = executables


    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An assertion error means that some assert thing in your "slither.py" is not getting asserted; why don't you try deleting that assertion line and try again. In other words, delete all the `assert` keyword lines and try again.